# Unable to call web service with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I have the following we service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tono.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I am able to call the HelloWorld method from html by doing:

```
<form action="http://localhost:10144/Services/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Invoke" class="button">
</form>
```

**Why am I not able to call it using ajax? why does the javascript code bellow fails?**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            utl: "http://localhost:10144/Services/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
            //data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                var test1 = response.d;
                var test2 = response.data;
            },
            error: function (er) {
                debugger;
            }
        });            
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `utl` should be `url` also the response doesn't seem to be json, that may also throw an arror

Comment: wow you are right! that typo just made me lose so much time! thanks!

Comment: This is a case for Facepalm! lol

Comment: I already did! lol. I wish the code will not run at all instead of going to the error function

Answer (score 1):

As stated above your utl should be url.

Also in your error function

```
error: function (er) {
                debugger;
            }
```

Change that to the following so the error would be shown to you and you can debug better.

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }
```